# How do I Add an EditText Dynamically to xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

XAMARIN ANDROID DYNAMIC CLICK: I want the spinner, edit text and positive button to be placed side by side such that when the button is clicked by any user, it regenrates the same content (spinner, edittext and a negative button) and for every click on the positive button the same thing happens while for every click on the negative button, the content where the negative button is will be removed.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layoutTeste"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spn"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/et" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:hint="Enter a Value"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnDisplay"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/et" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically you can create view in xamarin android programmatically for your need.

For Example

```
LinearLayout LL = FindViewById<LinearLayout(Resource.Id.Linear_MS); //root layout
var param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        param.SetMargins(20, 20, 20, 10);
var et = new EditText(this);
LL.AddView(et, param);
```

In Xml side by side design use this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layoutTeste"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spn"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/et" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:hint="Enter a Value"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDisplay"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnDisplay"
        android:layout_weight="1"
      />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but, what if I want the edittext to be added from a button click? and each time a new edittext is added, a button appears alongside it for another **edittext** to be added and the old button disappears

Comment: You just add this code in button click event. 
btn.Click += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
}

Comment: You just need button as static and dynamic edittext create seperate linearlayout to hold all edittexts.

Comment: sorry to bother you _Mohamed Mohaideen AH_ but this is the code i'm trying to regenerate multiple times from a single button click exactly the way it is:  **Pls look up, my code has been re-edited**. Thanks

Comment: and not just the edittext but the spinner and a negative button shld be generated on the same line. Plsss